# Electron.js: Requiring a remote module doesn't let the script work

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I want to add a custom title for my frameless window with custom buttons.

I have two script files - `index.js`, which runs automatically on Electron launching, and `app.js`, which added in `index.html` with `<script src>` tag.

There's a problem - `require()` doesn't let the script work - none of lines is running if I require any module, nevermind what it is.

index.html:

```html
<head>
    ...
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    ...
</head>
```

index.js

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const sass = require('sass')
const fs = require('fs')

// Creates a main window
function createWindow () {
    renderStylesheets()
    let mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        resizable: true,
        transparent: true,
        frame: false,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    })
    mainWindow.loadFile('index.html').then(() => {})
}

...
```

app.js

```js
alert("This alert won't show.")

// If I remove these lines, alerts and jQuery's "$(callback)" will run, but
// button actions won't work :(
const { BrowserWindow, app } = require('electron').remote;
let window = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();

alert("This alert won't show and the $(() => {}) won't run too.")

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `app.js` and any other scripts have not a `require` function. To add an access to Node.js function outside the main script, I set `nodeIntegration: true` and `contextIsolation: false` into the window initializer:

```js
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 900,
        height: 600,
        resizable: true,
        transparent: true,
        show: true,
        frame: false,
        center: true,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
            nodeIntegration: true,    // <- This one
            contextIsolation: false,  // <- And this one
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Where is the problem? If it is in `index.html` then the problem is with line 4 of what is shown. Make sure that you are referencing the correct website and that you are referencing the correct data.

If the problem is in `index.js` then the problem may be on line 8 of what is shown as you need to make sure that the variable "app" is mentioned or stated with a value before line 8.

Those are the only two things that I see right away that might be contributing to this problem.

Hope that this helps.